# plotting multiple scatterplot from the same file

Tags: r

I have this [data](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/blob/main/fig52222.csv) , it has 6 groups, I want to plot multiple scatterplots, I'm trying to use spearsman equation to plot each case separate and then combine them in on figure, this is what I'm looking for

[image]

This is my code:

```
fig5ctrial<-read.csv("fig52222.csv")
str(fig5ctrial)

alphacell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(1:4)],"./alphacell.csv", row.names = FALSE)
betacell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(5:8)],"./betacell.csv", row.names = FALSE)
gammacell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(9:12)],"./gammacell.csv", row.names = FALSE)
deltacell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(13:16)],"./deltacell.csv", row.names = FALSE)
acinarcell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(17:20)],"./acinarcell.csv", row.names = FALSE)
ductalcell <- write.csv(fig5ctrial[,c(21:24)],"./ductalcell.csv", row.names = FALSE)


alphacellv<-read.csv("alphacell.csv")
betacellv<-read.csv("betacell.csv")
gammacellv<-read.csv("gammacell.csv")
deltacellv<-read.csv("deltacell.csv")
acinarcellv<-read.csv("acinarcell.csv")
ductalcellv<-read.csv("ductalcell.csv")

head(alphacellv)
head(betacellv)
head(gammacellv)
head(deltacellv)
head(acinarcellv)
head(ductalcellv)

attach(alphacellv)
z1<-plot(X...donor., a.cells, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p alpha cells ", pch=19)

attach(betacellv)
z2<-plot(X...donor..1, b.cells, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p beta cells ", pch=19)

attach(gammacellv)
z3<-plot(X...donor..2, g.cells, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p gamma cells ", pch=19)

attach(deltacellv)
z4<-plot(X...donor..3, d.cells, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p delta cells ", pch=19)

attach(acinarcellv)
z5<-plot(X...donor..4, X...cell.type., main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p acinar cells ", pch=19)

attach(ductalcellv)
z6<-plot(X...donor..5, X...cell.type..1, main="Scatterplot Example", xlab="Spearsman p all cells ", ylab="Spearsman p ductal cells ", pch=19)

z7<-plot(X...cell.type..1 ~X...donor..5, col="lightgreen", pch=19,data=(ductalcellv))

library("ggplot2")
library("cowplot")
library("gridExtra")
#grid.arrange did not work
grid.arrange(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7, nrow=3, ncol=3)
#for i in X...cell.type..1 {if i >= 0.6 then text(X...cell.type..1 ~X...donor..5, labels=rownames(ductalcellv),data=ductalcellv, cex=0.9, font=2)}

#plot_grid did not work
plot_grid(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7, nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

How to achieve this?